# Sharepoint Military Time in List

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list and in a few columns I want the end users to be able to input military time.  Would I have to create a calc. value or is there a drop down option.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Give the link below a shot. It looks like you'll need to use a calculated column.

http://roneiceboggersonsblog.blogspot.com/2013/08/show-only-time-in-your-sharepoint-column.html